# How to use Python iteration to read paragraphs, tables and pictures in word？

Tags: python, django, python-docx

So far, I've found a way to read paragraphs and tables in word sequentially and iteratively, but I'm stuck with how to read pictures sequentially.
I would like to ask you to help me on the basis of the original code to achieve how the sequence of iteration word pictures?
Here is my current code

```
from docx.document import Document as _Document
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.table import _Cell, Table, _Row
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
import docx
path = './test.docx'
doc = docx.Document(path)

def iter_block_items(parent):
    if isinstance(parent, _Document):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    elif isinstance(parent, _Row):
        parent_elm = parent._tr
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")
    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)

for block in iter_block_items(doc):
    # read Paragraph
    if isinstance(block, Paragraph):
        print(block.text)
    # read table
    elif isinstance(block, Table):
        print(block.style.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify `iter_block_items` such that the iteration body handles the case of a picture: currently it only handles (and yields) paragraphs and tables.

I don't really know the format, but you might want docx.oxml.shape.CT_Picture for the "flag type". Browsing through its documentation, python-docx doesn't seem to have a picture version of the Table or Paragraph wrappers though.